# Is there way to add Q objects in django?

Tags: python, django

I am passing multiple values in a list and I want to filter my queryset with this values. I know about Q object but I don't know how to add filters together. I thought of something like:

```
categories = ['1','3','4']

for category in categories:
    Q+= Q(id = category)
```

and after that I would filter my queryset `queryset.filter(Q)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you don't need `Q` if you just want to filter by IDs:

```py
queryset.filter(id__in=categories)
```

Answer (score 5):

as answered earlier in this particular case you don't need `Q`, you can use `__in` filter. if for any reason you want to use `Q` it would be this way:

```
from django.db.models import Q
q_list = Q()
for category in categories:
    q_list |= Q(id=category)
result_queryset = ModelName.objects.filter(q_list)
```